# Custom push notification to mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, server-push

I am searching for information about custom push notification. 
I want to implement a tunnel between server and devices (Android and iOS). When it comes a time server should send information to device (App).

Also as i know push works just in one way and server don't know if it's message has reached device. Maybe i am wrong at this statement, so please correct me.

I my case i want that server could know this information. So my question would be how to create this behavior between server and device (Android, iOS). Maybe there are some libraries or even protocol name where i should look.

At this moment i am reading about push notification named [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/)

I would appreciate for any information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) for Android, and [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) on the iOS side. (There's also Azure in Windows Mobile, but nobody really seems to care due to the cost.

And yes, you're correct in your assertion that push notifications are one-way. However, it is relatively simple to provide an acknowledgement path back to the server, if the device is in connectivity. In response to the notification, you can simply have the device post a token to the server, confirming the receipt of the push notification.

Comment: This isn't what i am looking. I know these really good. I want my own implementation. It's really not push notification what i am searching, but i don't know how to name it. Maybe hanging transaction or session. But thank you for helping

Comment: MQTT is for always-on connected devices. Implementing your own push services using GCM or APNS as the transport layer is the clever thing to do: This sort of thing is far from trivial, so relying on a known solution will save you a tremendous development effort.